# BigQuery SQL via Apps Scripts filtering by DATE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

This is my first time working with BigQuery.

I have an automation in a Google Sheet file which runs daily and inserts some data into my table.

In this moment I have ~120k rows in the table.

The schema is very simple:

```
Field name | Type
Date       | DATE
Country    | STRING
Revenue    | FLOAT
```

I'm trying get a sum of all revenue in last 7 days.

When I'm running this query in BigQuery console, I get the right value:

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS sum FROM my_dataset.my_table WHERE Date > '2020-10-01'
```

Now, I have copied the exact same query in my Apps Script following [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) from Google Developers but I don't get any result for the query. It only writes the header value in my sheet, the result value is always null.

I've tested a lot of queries and I figured out that only the queries with `WHERE Date` clause are not working. I'm looking for a an answer for a few hours now and I think I've tried everything.

Any tip on how can I format this query to get the data I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after scratching my head for a week I found the problem. I don't really understand how Google Cloud platform works, but I find it strange.

I didn't changed anything code wise, only activated Google Apps Script API in the project. This solved my issue. And still don't understand why it was possible to run some queries without API access, but I guess this is how GCP works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it using **`useLegacySql: false`** in my request object.

```
const request = {
    query: `SELECT * FROM ${dataset}.${table} WHERE DATE>'${startDate}' ORDER BY DATE ASC;`,
    useLegacySql: false,
    location: location,
  };
```

Now it's working fine :)